# are there any servercrash reports on debian or logs?

Tags: debian, crash-reports

My server crashes sometimes for no obvious reason (Debian squeeze).

Are there any global reports or logs where I can get a hint, why?

I only know `/var/log/syslog`
but there isn't any hint

Or are there tools, that is should install to get more information next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global errors are logged in /var/log/messages. 
It can be accessed using dmesg.